# change top value of a row without any changes on background-size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have this code snippet that i have background for whole body and i have row that contains a button i want to change top value of it for the button comes down and keep responsivity for devices. 100% for background size not work and i set 1700% and it is weird
and my main problem is top 50% doesn't do anything

```css
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
  body{
      background: url("../images/background.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100% 1700%;
  }
  .buttonBox{
      /*margin-top: 130%;*/
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      top:50%
  }
  .buttonBox button{
      font-size: 4vw;
      width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row buttonBox">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <button class="btn btn-success text-center">دانلود و نصب</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for .buttonBox top position to work, you would need to give its container element .container a fixed height, e.g.:

```
.container {
  height: 35px;
}
```

Note though that top: 50% will be 50% of the container height. If you want to make it 50% of the page height, you might have more success using VH instead of %

```
.buttonBox {
  top: 50vh;
}
```